# Доступ к свойствам контрола вложенного в свой контрол

Tags: c#

Есть свой контрол с тремя полями:

```
public partial class myTextBox : UserControl
    {
        ...
        public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox UCtextBox;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label UClabel;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel UCPanel;
        ...
    }
```

Можно ли сделать, чтоб к полю
`myTextBox1.UCtextBox.Text`
я обращался так:
`myTextBox1.Text`,
сохраняя при этом приватность поля System.Windows.Forms.TextBox UCtextBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public partial class myTextBox : UserControl {
    ...
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox UCtextBox;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label UClabel;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Panel UCPanel;
    ...
    public override string Text { get => UCtextBox.Text; set => UCtextBox.Text = value; }
}
```

Над событиями, если они нужны, тоже придётся поработать.

Comment: Точно! А меня смутило, что все свойства, которые я определил, в панели свойств появились, а Text не появился. А в остальном работает. Только еще нужно добавить ключевое слово  override или new

Comment: Override подойдёт, так как сигнатура и уровень доступа не меняется.